# Error while writing to file: throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'Function', value); Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

`

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile("datafile.txt", "utf-8", function(err, data){
    let newData = "Some string to write in file";

    fs.writeFile("datafile.txt",  newData, (err) => { 
        if (err) 
          console.log(err); 
        else { 
          console.log("File written successfully\n"); 
          console.log(fs.readFile("datafile.txt", "utf-8")); 
        } 
      }); 
})
```

`

The data has been written successfully but having this error on line with fs.readFile() at the end.
Can anyone help me figure it out?
Thanks.

## Complete error

> node file.js

```
File written successfully

node:internal/validators:455
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'Function', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "cb" argument must be of type function. Received type string ('utf-8')
    at maybeCallback (node:fs:178:3)
    at Object.readFile (node:fs:369:14)
    at D:\file.js:16:26
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:189:23) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Node.js v20.10.0

I am probably expecting some issue with async file but still not sure how to solve it.

EDIT:
TLDR: I want to make some changes to the file and then read the file again and check if the changes were done or not.

Comment: i.e. you want `{ encoding: "utf-8" }` if you want to specify the encoding

Comment: It takes a string as second argument as well, in that case that is taken to mean the encoding. But the examples I am finding on the net use the value `utf8`, not `utf-8` - so my guess would be, it doesn't recognize the latter as a valid encoding, and therefor thinks you must have meant to pass a callback function via the second parameter(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue,

The error was due to the fs.readfile not being synchronous in nature. I only had to update it to,

```
else { 
      console.log("File written successfully\n"); 
      console.log(fs.readFileSync("datafile.txt", "utf-8")); 
    }
```

instead of

```
else { 
          console.log("File written successfully\n"); 
          console.log(fs.readFile("datafile.txt", "utf-8")); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

fs.readFile takes 3 or 2(if encoding is not passed) arguments,

1. filename <- required
2. encoding <- optional
3. callback <- required

data read from readFile will be passed to this callback function

```
fs.readFile("datafile.txt", "utf-8", (error, data) => {
if(error){
throw new Error('File Read Error');
}
console.log(data);
})
```

Please do proper research and read docs before jumping into stackoverflow.
Good Luck!
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-file-system/

Comment: Thank you so much for making time and providing a suggestion but I have found the solution. 

PS. Why would I be posting a question and wasting my time if I could have found it on the very first page it shows during the research? 
I couldn't find the solution for what I had in mind so yeah I posted a question. Please don't be rude without understanding the question.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you received indicates that there is an issue with the argument type being passed to a function in your code. Specifically, the error points to the use of the readFile function from the Node.js fs module.

The readFile function expects the second argument to be a callback function, but in your code, it appears to be a string ('utf-8') instead. To resolve this error, you need to provide a valid callback function as the second argument to readFile.

Here's an example of how to use readFile correctly:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('path/to/file.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  // Do something with the file data
  console.log(data);
});
```

In this example, the second argument to readFile is the encoding ('utf-8'), and the third argument is the callback function that will be executed when the file is read. The callback function takes two parameters, err and data, and you can handle any errors or process the file data within the callback.

Comment: Thank you so much for making time and providing a suggestion but I wanted to write and then read the file again to check the changes if they were done or not.